# Is using RESTful (json) on desktop app is good idea?

Tags: javascript, c#, android

Im planning to build cross platform app.
Android app, Web based app (js/vue), and desktop (windows wpf), all have the same database, is using RESTful is a good idea?
consider i dont have to rewrite database procedure for each platform.

Comment: Why should it be any less useful on desktop compared to mobile?

Comment: I need to print to EPSON dot matrix using ESC/POS script, so i need desktop app for direct communication to printer. and mobile just to CRUD.

Comment: What does that have to do with you question?

Comment: Didn't you answer your own question when you said "consider i dont have to rewrite database procedure for each platform"?

Answer (score 1):

Yes RESTful API would be great :)